# python: traceback.print_stack(): How to colorize and reformat output

Tags: python, pretty-print, traceback

I want to see the full trace of the code till a particular point

so i do

```
...
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
...
```

Then it will show

```
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __iter__
    return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1052, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 110, in execute
    extra={'duration': duration, 'sql': sql, 'params': params}
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1371, in debug
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1519, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1528, in handle
    if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 762, in filter
    result = f.filter(record)
  File "basic_django/settings.py", line 402, in filter
    traceback.print_stack()
```

How to make this output more colorful using pygments.

Generally to colorize a json string in python i do

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import JsonLexer
from pygments.formatters import TerminalTrueColorFormatter
json_str = '{ "name":"John" }'
print(highlight(json_str, JsonLexer(), TerminalTrueColorFormatter()))
```

Similarly how to do that with `traceback.print_stack()`

**Answer I Used based on Alexander Huszagh**

1) we have to use `Python3TracebackLexer`

2) we have to use `traceback.format_stack()` which gives a `list` and then concatenate them as a `string` using `''.join(traceback.format_stack())`.

```
import traceback
import pygments
from pygments.lexers import Python3TracebackLexer
from pygments.formatters import TerminalTrueColorFormatter
traceback_color = pygments.highlight(''.join(traceback.format_stack()),Python3TracebackLexer(),TerminalTrueColorFormatter(style='trac')) # trac or rainbow_dash i prefer
print(traceback_color)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygments lists the available [lexers](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/). You can do this with Python3TracebackLexer.

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import Python3TracebackLexer
from pygments.formatters import TerminalTrueColorFormatter

err_str = '''
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __iter__
    return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1052, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 110, in execute
    extra={'duration': duration, 'sql': sql, 'params': params}
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1371, in debug
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1519, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1528, in handle
    if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 762, in filter
    result = f.filter(record)
  File "basic_django/settings.py", line 402, in filter
    traceback.print_stack()
'''

print(highlight(err_str, Python3TracebackLexer(), TerminalTrueColorFormatter()))
```

In order to get `err_str`, replace `print_stack` with `format_stack` as follows than do:

```
def colorize_traceback(err_str):
    return highlight(err_str, Python3TracebackLexer(), TerminalTrueColorFormatter())

try:
    ... # Some logic
except Exception:   # Or a more narrow exception
    # tb.print_stack()
    print(colorize_traceback(tb.format_stack()))
```

Comment: How to get `err_str`. Because `traceback.print_stack()` itself prints it and cannot save it to a variable

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, use the [rich](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich) library.

[With just two lines of code](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/traceback.html), it will prettify your tracebacks... and then some!

```py
from rich.traceback import install
install()
```

How does it look afterwards? Take a gander:

[image: Fabulous traceback output]

And the beauty of it? [It supports Pygment themes](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/traceback.html#rich.traceback.install)!